# Grails List Restful Resources return Unexpected results

Tags: rest, grails

I'm trying to build a restful api with grails. Now for resource listing I got a weird response:

```
{
   "empty": false,
   "totalCount": 229
}
```

But if I try to show a specific resource i.e  /resource/1 I got expected response. What is going wrong with this?

Comment: You will have add more information to the question and show how resource controller look like.

Comment: The controller is just a RestfulController without any modifications.

Comment: I recently upgraded from grails 2.4 to 2.4.4. I don't know if this is related to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems indeed that the origin of the problem is related to the version of Grails. I do not know if you found a solution in the meanwhile, but I just stumbled upon this problem and found this bug report: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11892

A workaround consists in appending `toArray()` to all lists of objects. If you are using `RestfulController` an example for the `index` method (supposing you want to return a list of objects) could be:

```
class BookController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    BookController() {
        super(Book)
    }

    @Override
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond listAllResources(params).toArray(), formats: ['json', 'xml']
    }
}
```

This will give you the expected result rather than the ou7tput you cite in your question.